# Inno Setup: Disable finish page

Tags: inno-setup

Wanna close window after installation. 
When progress bar has reached the end.
How to do that?

4 example: inno unpacks another app, which runs after inno ends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`DisableFinishedPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablefinishedpage) directive value to `yes`:

```
[Setup]
DisableFinishedPage=yes
```